# Android MediaFormat:KEY_REPEAT_PREVIOUS_FRAME_AFTER setting

Tags: android, video

what does it mean this setting: `KEY_REPEAT_PREVIOUS_FRAME_AFTER` for `MediaFormat` (video format).
From [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaFormat.html):

*Applies only when configuring a video encoder in "surface-input" mode. The associated value is a long and gives the time in microseconds after which the frame previously submitted to the encoder will be repeated (once) if no new frame became available since.
Constant Value: "repeat-previous-frame-after"*

I found typical usage: `format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_REPEAT_PREVIOUS_FRAME_AFTER, 1000000 / FRAME_RATE);`

but i do not understand it. Could you explain me, which long number is good for which situations?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I know about the Android MediaCodec, if you configure the surface-input for encoder, encoder will only encode-output a frame WHEN SURFACE HAS UPDATED.

This means if your surface presents static (e.g. keep staying in launcher screen), the encoder will not be notified to output any new frame.

It is more efficient but some applications don't love it because they expect the output stream is continuous. Then they need to setup the KEY_REPEAT_PREVIOUS_FRAME_AFTER value.

Alright, let's check the suggestion formula: (1000000 / frameRate) in micro-second.

The frameRate is so-called FPS (frame-per-second) which means you want to update N frames in one second period.

So it is clear, if you configure frameRate as 60 fps, it means you need to generate 1 frame in 1000000/60 micro-second ~= 16 ms. If your surface did not have any update after 16 ms, the encoder will not output a encoded-frame unless you set the KEY_REPEAT_PREVIOUS_FRAME_AFTER.

In a word, there is NO best setting about this value, it depends on your application usage.

Hope this explanation helpful.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.